# Connect SharePoint List across different site collections

Tags: web-services, data-view-web-part, soap, infopath-data-connections

I have a Office 365 account with SharePoint Online.

I would like to share on a public site a list hosted at another site collection. I've tried SOAP service following these posts:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/93558/Displaying-a-SharePoint-List-from-another-team-sit

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/cizi/2010/08/01/connect-to-another-library-in-sharepoint-designer-2010

But when I edit a page and select a SOAP service created before, SharePoint Designer can't get data from this data source.

I've tried through a SOAP Web Service in Infopath forms too, but no success yet.

Could anyone help me please? Am I on a correct way? Thanks.